# Displaying Camera footage through a web service / web site - How?

Tags: web-services, camera

I would like to somehow feed by camera feed through a web service / site to be viewed over the web.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I have C#, ASP.NET, Silverlight, and WCF experience already.  How does one hook into cameras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to do video or just frames from the camera?

For video, I recommend using a flash player and some sort of flash media server, like [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5).  You can encode using the flash media encoder.

If you just want to display frames, most camera software will dump a frame for you, and you can display it like any other image.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your response.  I would like to stay within the MS stack, i.e. Silverlight.  I've never done this before and thus don't know how to start.  Can you give me some general concepts I might be able to research?  For example, you noted 'encoder', so I'll look that up.  Anything other key terms I should look for regarding SL and video?

Comment: Yes, so you need some sort of capture device... like a webcam.  Then you need to encode that video into something like MPEG-4 or WMV.  Then you stream that to a server.  The server then streams it to all of the clients.  On the client end, there is a player, which I suppose you could do in Silverlight.